# How to have circle roll when pushed using MatterJS?

Tags: javascript, matter.js

I have a simple animation where I have a static rectangle slowly moving horizontally so that it pushes a circle across the 'floor'.

How can I make the circle roll instead of slide?

I tried adding friction to the circle and the floor, and removing friction from the pushing rectangle, but it makes no difference.

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var w = 1000;
var h = 500;

const Engine = Matter.Engine;
const Render = Matter.Render;
const World = Matter.World;
const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
const MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;
const Bounds = Matter.Bounds;
const Events = Matter.Events;
const Body = Matter.Body;

const engine = Engine.create();

const render = Render.create({
  element: container,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: w,
    height: h,
    wireframes: true,
    showAngleIndicator: true,
    background: 'transparent',
  }
});

var boxX = 10;
var boxY = 390;
const ball = Bodies.circle(100, 400, 80, {
  friction: 100
});
const box = Bodies.rectangle(boxX, boxY, 20, 20, {
  friction: 0,
  isStatic: true
});
const floor = Bodies.rectangle(500, 480, 1000, 20, {
  isStatic: true
});

World.add(engine.world, [
  ball,
  box,
  floor
]);

engine.gravity.y = 3;

Matter.Runner.run(engine);
Render.run(render);

move();

function move() {
  boxX += 1;
  Matter.Body.setPosition(box, {
    x: boxX,
    y: boxY
  }, [updateVelocity = true]);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(move);
};
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js" integrity="sha512-0z8URjGET6GWnS1xcgiLBZBzoaS8BNlKayfZyQNKz4IRp+s7CKXx0yz7Eco2+TcwoeMBa5KMwmTX7Kus7Fa5Uw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I've created a runable snippet. Please review my edits and make sure the correct matterjs lib is being included

Comment: Consider rotating the ball with a couple degrees each animation/frame

Comment: @DarkBee I want it to roll naturally, so that I can eventually push it off a ledge and let it do it's own thing after that.

Comment: If you move the pushing box up to, say, `y = 350`, the circle rolls. If you want it to look like the pushing box is exactly at the center of the circle, then you could use an invisible box to do the actual pushing and render the old centered pushing box but make it non-colliding.

Comment: @ggorlen Maybe if I used a many sided polygon instead of the circle it would help, combined with what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation I found that you need to add [slop](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Body.html#property_slop) to the floor body to allow the circle to have enough grip to roll.

```
const floor = Bodies.rectangle( 500 , 480, 1000, 20, { friction: 1, slop: 1, isStatic: true } );
```